# Optimizing jQuery Script to Hide/Show Items in 1000-Item Set Based on Live Text Input

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following script for a page which has been loaded with a data set of about 1000 items (all in one server call--no AJAX).  ***On each keyup*** the script converts the text input into a CSS-standards-friendly string (removes spaces, downcases, etc.), then matches that string with CSS classes that I've loaded each item with, and adjusts the "hide" or "show" accordingly for that element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.players li').hide();      
    $("#filter-input").keyup(function () {
        var lowercase = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var spaced = lowercase.replace(/[ _]/, '-');
        var outputString = spaced.replace(/[^a-z-]/i, '');
        $('ul.players li').hide();      
        $('ul.players li[class*="'+outputString+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

Example of HTML this is working on:

```
<form>
    <input id="filter-input" type="text" />
</form>
<ul class="players">
    <li class="firstname lastname teamname position cityname">
        <div>Basic player info here...</div>
    </li>
</ul
```

The script is working just fine (in the simple capacity that I need it to work)--but it's very laggy.  **What can I do to optimize this for performance?**

*(Obviously, there are a lot of class switches across those many elements--I don't think I can avoid that--but maybe there's something to be done about the string conversions)*

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML so we can see the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to insert a `<style>` element in the head that matches them - this will be a lot quicker.

```
 $('head').append('<style id="player-style"></style>');
```

When a key is pressed - edit this style:

```
 $('#player-style').html('.' + outputString + ' { display: block }');
```

*Note that you might have to use `.text()` to replace the contents - haven't tried it.*

Just to mention that you will need some more CSS to hide all `ul.players li` and show only the needed with the trick above. I think this will be fast enough, since the browser will be doing the showing and hiding.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this solution (great lateral thinking).  I'm running into what seems to be a kind of inheritance problem, though: Assuming I declared `ul.players li {display: none}` in my CSS, your script reveals players of the given class as desired, but it doesn't re-hide those disqualified as I continue to type (_matches for "rod" are still displayed as I type "rodgers"_).  I can fix that by re-`.hide()`-ing all players after each `keyup`--but that seems to override the `style` element I appended to the `head` (so, ultimately, no `li` are displayed).  Any thoughts?

Comment: Edit the style in question, rather then adding a new one.

Comment: That works splendidly ; )  I changed the style-editing line to `$('#player-style').html('ul.players li[class*="'+outputString+'"] { display: block }');` to enable partial class names to be matched (aiding the live feedback).  I'm still having some lag in Safari on the initial run of the script (everything's snappy on every subsequent keyup), but I'm willing to chalk that up to poor indexing of some kind just in that browser... not sure that can be avoided, given the number of items involved.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your jQuery selectors as fast as possible. In general, selecting items by a class name is slow. It is good that you have begun your selectors with the element type (as this is quick). But where possible you should avoid class selection. Is there only one item matched by $("ul.players") ? If so consider giving it an ID and using that.

Also, selecting $('ul.players li') is sub-optimal as it will try to match any "li" elements within the list. But in actual fact you actually want ALL direct descendants of the list. Try replacing it with $("ul.players").children() .

Finally, don't run selectors more than necessary, instead store them to a variable. Here's the final output:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var players = $("ul.players").children(),
        output = $("#filter-output");
    players.hide();      
    $("#filter-input").keyup(function () {
        players.hide();      
        output.text($(this).val()
            .toLowerCase()
            .replace(/[ _]/, '-')
            .replace(/[^a-z-]/i, ''));
        players.filter('[class*="'+outputString+'"]').show();
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how much speed gain you'll get but worth a try :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation to accompany the code--very helpful.  I changed the "output.text($(this).val()" line to "outputString = ($(this).val()" to get the script to work, and removed the "output = $("#filter-output");" line altogether (to match an edit I made to the original question).

Comment: the biggest cause of the slowness in the question will be the .show() call on x elements causing lots of redraws which you have not addressed!